# Does the limit of the union (intersection) of 2 sets equal the union (intersection) of the limits?

Tags: limits, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we have two sequences of sets $A_n$ and $B_n$ such that $A_n \to A$ and $B_n \to B$

i.) Does $A_n \bigcup B_n \to A \bigcup B$

and

ii.) Does $A_n \bigcap B_n \to A \bigcap B$

If not, is there a counterexample?

$$$$
I don't think the limit should hold.

$$$$

For example, 
$\liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n \bigcup B_n \neq \liminf_{n\to\infty} A_n \bigcup \liminf_{n\to\infty} B_n$.

This is apparent if we take $A_n = \{{(-1)^n}\}$ and $B_n = \{{(-1)^{n+1}}\}$.

The same $A_n$ and $B_n$ show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n \bigcap B_n \neq \limsup_{n\to\infty} A_n \bigcap \limsup_{n\to\infty} B_n$.

On the other hand, per [Proof that lim sup of union equals union of lim sup](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1911034/proof-that-lim-sup-of-union-equals-union-of-lim-sup), the relation holds for $\limsup$ in the case of union and $\liminf$ in the case of intersection. I've also worked through both of those cases but am stuck here, and I'm not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: Your argumentation, while accurate, doesn't use the assumption that $\lim A_n$ and $\lim B_n$ actually exist. I suspect this actually means that the limit of the union is the union of the limits and similarly for the intersection.

Comment: @GregMartin you're right. Equality of $\limsup$ and $\liminf$ are crucial here.

Comment: What exactly is meant by "$A_n$ converges to $A$" ?..... BTW, $x\in \lim\inf A_n$ iff $\{n\in \Bbb N:x\not \in A_n\}$ is finite, while $x\in \lim\sup A_n$ iff $\{n: x\in A_n\}$ is infinite, which can be useful.

Answer (score 2):

Took a step back, thought about the problem more, and it became clear the limits distribute.

**Useful Facts**

1. $\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \subset \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n$

since $\omega \in A_n$  $\forall n\geq N$  $\implies \omega \in A_n$ i.o.

2. $\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap B_n \subset \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap \limsup_{n \to \infty} B_n$

since $\omega \in A_n \cap B_n$ i.o. $\implies \omega \in A_n$ i.o. and $\omega \in B_n$ i.o.

3. $\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup \liminf_{n \to \infty} B_n \subset \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup B_n$

since $\omega \in A_n$ or $\omega \in B_n$ $\forall n \geq N$ $\implies$ $\omega \in A_n \cup B_n$ $\forall n \geq N$

4. $\limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup B_n = \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup \limsup_{n \to \infty} B_n$

(see link above)

5. $\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap B_n = \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap \liminf_{n \to \infty} B_n$

since $\omega \in A_n \cap B_n$ $\forall n \geq N$, then $\omega \in A_n$ and $\omega \in B_n$ $\forall n \geq N$

$$$$

**Proofs**

*I. If $A_n \to A$ and $B_n \to B$, then $\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup B_n = A \cup B = \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup B_n$*
$$A \cup B = \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup \liminf_{n \to \infty} B_n \subset \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup B_n \subset \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup B_n = \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup \limsup_{n \to \infty} B_n = A \cup B$$

$$\implies \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup B_n = A \cup B = \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cup B_n$$

By (3), (1), and (4)

$$$$
*II. If $A_n \to A$ and $B_n \to B$, then $\liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap B_n = A \cap B = \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap B_n$*
$$$$
$$A \cap B = \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap \liminf_{n \to \infty} B_n = \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap B_n \subset \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap B_n \subset \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap \limsup_{n \to \infty} B_n = A \cap B$$

$$\implies \liminf_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap B_n = A \cap B = \limsup_{n \to \infty} A_n \cap B_n$$

By (5), (1), and (2)